# Use min function without grouping

Tags: t-sql

How can I retrieve the `min` of a date without `group by`?

```
declare @table table 
(
    SaleDate date
)
insert into @table
select '7/8/2021' union
select '7/21/2021'



declare @dimdate table
(
    fulldate date,
    WeekNumberOfYear int
)
insert into @dimdate
select '7/4/2021', 28 union
select '7/5/2021', 28 union
select '7/6/2021', 28 union
select '7/7/2021', 28 union
select '7/8/2021', 28 union
select '7/9/2021', 28 union
select '7/10/2021', 28 union
select '7/11/2021', 29 union
select '7/18/2021', 30 union
select '7/19/2021', 30 union
select '7/20/2021', 30 union
select '7/21/2021', 30 union
select '7/22/2021', 30 union
select '7/23/2021', 30 union
select '7/24/2021', 30


select datepart(week, saledate) 'wk', 
min(fulldate) as 'Beginning_Week' 
from @table t inner join @dimdate d on
datepart(week, saledate) = WeekNumberOfYear
group by datepart(week, saledate), WeekNumberOfYear
```

How can I retrieve the same result as above without a group by?

Comment: Use a windowed aggregate instead.

Comment: Could provide the DimDate table also?

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select dt,
(select min(WeekNumberOfYear) from DimDate) as minWeekNumberOfYear
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a windowed aggregate:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       MIN(dt) OVER () AS MinDt
FROM @table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` window function if you partition by `WeekNumberOfYear` and use `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` statement so that there are no duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       d.WeekNumberOfYear wk, 
       MIN(fulldate) OVER (PARTITION BY d.WeekNumberOfYear) Beginning_Week 
FROM @table t INNER JOIN @dimdate d 
ON DATEPART(week, t.saledate) = d.WeekNumberOfYear;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f04d1acfd3b4c60e2709c6b6ed4bf382).