# Use min() when row_number() is descending

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have `@Tickets` table with 2 open tickets for *JFK*.

```
declare @Tickets table
(
    Airport varchar(10),
    TicketNum varchar(10),
    Created date,
    Modified date,
    LastModified date,
    Modified_By varchar(10),
    TicketStatus varchar(10), 
    AssignedTo varchar(10)
)
insert into @Tickets
select 'JFK', '001', '9/25/2021', '9/26/2021', '9/29/2021', 'Jimmy', 'Open', 'Ralph' union
select 'JFK', '002', '9/28/2021', '9/28/2021', '9/30/2021', 'Mary', 'Open', 'Andrew'

select Airport, lastmodified, assignedto, Modified_By
from
(
  select airport, lastmodified, assignedto, Modified_By,
    row_number() over(partition by airport order by lastmodified desc) rn
  from @Tickets
) src
where rn = 1
```

The following returns the *last modified* date of JFK tickets (*9/30/2021*), the last person that modified any of the JFK tickets (*Mary*) and the owner of the ticket that Mary last modified (*Andrew*).

```
Airport   lastmodified  assignedto  Modified_By
JFK       2021-09-30    Andrew      Mary
```

What I can't figure out is how to show `min(created)` to show when the first ticket was created.

The complete result should be

```
Airport   First_Created  lastmodified  assignedto   Modified_By
JFK       2021-09-25     2021-09-30    Andrew       Mary
```

How can I plug in a `min(create_date) as 'First_Created'` in the query above?

I'm sure I can have two `cte` like below and then a `join`, but I prefer not using joins unless there are no other options:

```
declare @Tickets table
(
    Airport varchar(10),
    TicketNum varchar(10),
    Created date,
    Modified date,
    LastModified date,
    Modified_By varchar(10),
    TicketStatus varchar(10), 
    AssignedTo varchar(10)
)
insert into @Tickets
select 'JFK', '001', '9/25/2021', '9/26/2021', '9/29/2021', 'Jimmy', 'Open', 'Ralph' union
select 'EWR', '001', '9/25/2021', '9/26/2021', '9/29/2021', 'Jimmy', 'Open', 'Ralph' union
select 'STI', '001', '9/25/2021', '9/26/2021', '9/29/2021', 'Jimmy', 'Open', 'Ralph' union
select 'JFK', '002', '9/28/2021', '9/28/2021', '9/30/2021', 'Mary', 'Open', 'Andrew'

;with cte as
(
    select Airport, lastmodified, assignedto, Modified_By
    from
    (
      select airport, lastmodified, assignedto, Modified_By,
        row_number() over(partition by airport order by lastmodified desc) rn
      from @Tickets
    ) src
    where rn = 1
), cte2 as
(
    select airport, min(created) as 'created' from @Tickets group by airport
)
select cte.Airport, lastmodified, assignedto, Modified_By, created  
from cte inner join cte2 on 
cte.Airport = cte2.Airport
```

Comment: Use a windowed aggregate as suggested in one of the answers to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475582/use-min-function-without-grouping)

Comment: I'll have to group by if I want to use `min()`. Even with the grouping, the result is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.  The query selects the latest modified row (partitioned by Airport) and CROSS APPLY's the earliest Created date.

```
with last_mod_cte as (
    select top 1 with ties * 
    from @tickets
    order by row_number() over(partition by airport order by lastmodified desc))
select lm.Airport, min_created.dt First_Created, lm.LastModified, lm.AssignedTo, lm.Modified_By
from last_mod_cte lm
     cross apply (select min(Created) 
                  from @Tickets t
                  where lm.Airport=t.Airport) min_created(dt);
```